# What are the novel features of the Ceylon programming language

Tags: programming-languages, ceylon

I know that it does not yet exists, but there is much talk and I wonder what the new features it hopes to brings to programming languages.

Comment: The fact that this question ranks third on Google for "ceylon programming language" seems to contradict the "there is much talk" part. In any case, go read the [presentation](http://in.relation.to/service/File/19159). There isn't much else about it around.

Comment: Now when I search Google it is #1 hit!  I only types it 5 minutes ago!

Comment: By the way: thanks for the mention. I'm on page 7 and I'm already starting to like it :)

Comment: Google seems to like stackoverflow a lot.

Comment: @MichaelBurr perhaps has got to with your web history. Google does try to personalize search results.

Comment: @EliSchneider See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117561/whats-the-difference-between-scala-and-red-hats-ceylon-language, might help